# Assigning a manually allocated UnsafeMutablePointer<String>

Tags: swift, memory-management, unsafe-pointers

I would like to assign the pointee's value of a pointer to String that is manually allocated.
In other words, I would like to write something like that:

```swift
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.allocate(1)
pointer.pointee = "Hello, World!"

// ...

pointer.deallocate()
```

Unfortunately, it appears that this code *sometimes* crashes at the second line (i.e. the assignment).

The same behavior can be observed if the pointee's type is an array.
However, it seems like this program never fails if the pointee's type does not contain a dynamically allocated storage (e.g. a simple `Int`).
This would suggest that the problem only occurs when the pointee's type wraps a pointer to the heap, such as `String` or `Array`.

Is there a way to work around this issue?

The reason I'm trying to achieve this is to create a generic memory arena.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer):

> Memory that has just been allocated through a typed pointer or has been deinitialized is in an uninitialized state.
>   Uninitialized memory must be initialized before it can be accessed for reading.

This explains why the code does not work.
The pointee's memory has been *allocated*, but it has not been *initialized* yet.
While this is irrelevant for simple value-types (e.g. `Int`), it is not for more complex types like `String` or `Array`.
These may contain pointers to heap memory that Swift's runtime manages behind the scene.
Hence, without a proper initialization, the runtime may crash when it attempts to perform operations on these hidden pointers.

In this particular example, the problem is that the runtime tries to release the memory previously assigned to the pointee (i.e. the underlying heap storage that contains the string's characters) before assigning a new value, but crashes since this memory was never allocated.

The program should be corrected as follows:

```swift
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.allocate(1)
pointer.initialize(to: "Hello, World!")

// ...

pointer.deallocate()
```

Comment: If you want a general buffer, that is what Data is. What you're doing here looks like a violation of general Swift memory principles and is probably headed for crashland.

Comment: I know this approach isn't Swifty. The goal is to create an efficient memory arena that'll be used by a factory to guarantee the uniqueness of the objects it creates. I could use classes, but  I would like to avoid memory allocations as much as possible.

Comment: Event when I use a pointer of `Int` type e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(1)`, it may still crash. I got the crash after a few dozens of trial.